# Using returned data to perform additional javascript tests with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

I have a mail.php file that gets called by an ajax script. For completeness, the ajax script is attached below.  All the mail.php file does is perform some server-side validation, and if everything passes, sends an email with `mail()` and the data sent from the ajax request.

What I want to do is perform some additional javascript actions based on the response of the request.  You can see that at its current state, the response of the request is simply echo'd to the screen, which is fine.  But now I want to modify HTML elements based on the response.

For example, say I want to append an image called "OK" to the page if the mail was sent, and else append an image called "FALSE" to the page if the mail was not sent.  What I'd like to do (in pseudocode) is this:

```
if ( request is OKAY ) $('.contact').append('<img src"OK"');
else ( $('.contact').append('<img src="BAD'');
```

Is there any way to perform this?

Thanks!

**The ajax script is shown below:**

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    $('div.load').html('<img src="images/load.gif" alt="Loading..." id="loading" />'); 

    //creation of variables to send
    var name = $('#name').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        phone = $('#phone').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone,

        success: function(result) {
            $('p.error,p.correct').remove();
            $('.contact').append(result);
            $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });

        }
    });

    return false; 
});
```

Comment: I should mention that I'd like to keep the current response there as well to make sure that non-JS users also get the appropriate message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your PHP responds with the text "OKAY":

```
if (result==="OKAY")
   $('.contact').append('<img src"OK" />');
else
   $('.contact').append('<img src="BAD" />');
```

Or:

```
$('.contact').append('<img src"' + (result==="OKAY"?'OK':'BAD') + '" />');
```

An alternative is to update your PHP so that it returns html that includes both a message and the image, e.g., on success it could return:

```
Your request was successful. <img src="OK" />
```

*"I should mention that I'd like to keep the current response there as well to make sure that non-JS users also get the appropriate message"*

Non-JS users will not be getting anything because your Ajax code uses JS...

Comment: Right, but if the PHP responds with a relatively long phrase which is not in English?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it responds with, just put that in the if condition: `if (result==="your relatively long phrase here")`.

Comment: non-JS users will see a blank page with the echo'd response of the php script.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point.  I can include the `img` in the echo'd response.  I might actually resort to doing that.  Thanks!

Comment: Testing a long phrase makes your code a bit brittle - I've shown that because that's what you asked about. Switching to a JSON response that includes a result code in one property and the actual message in another is more reliable - as mentioned in Jan's answer. But given the code you already have simply including the `<img>` in the echoed response would be the smallest change to your code to get it working.

Comment: I agree with you completely.  I think for now, I'll make the smallest change necessary.  However, I will experiment on the side to try and convert this to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want the server-side handler to return its status via the response, e.g. formatted as JSON (PHP has a function for that).

To achieve that and still get a good response for non-JavaScript users, too, I suggest using a different URL in the AJAX than in your form's `action` attribute, e.g. with an extra query parameter à la `?json=1`. Then your script can normally do its standard output and return easily parseable JSON (e.g. an associative array containing both the current response text and a status code) if the parameter is present. jQuery's AJAX interface can automatically parse the response as JSON if you tell it to.

Comment: Ahhh, this is intriguing!!  I was aware of the phrase comparison as suggested by @nnnnnn (though I was unsure whether it'll work for a foreign language).  But having the ability to return multiple variables and attributes is phenomenal.  I'll definitely look into JSON!

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of the success / error objects in the initialization of the AJAX call. You'll want to add three failure cases. The first two failure cases will come through the `success` ajax call, both due to server side issues. The second error case will be in the `error`case of the ajax call. Also, your web service should return a success parameter. Alter your code to something like this to achieve what you've described:

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    $('div.load').html('<img src="images/load.gif" alt="Loading..." id="loading" />'); 

    //creation of variables to send
    var name = $('#name').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        phone = $('#phone').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone,

        success: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $(".contact").append("<img src='OK.jpg'>");
                    $('p.error,p.correct').remove();
                    $('.contact').append(result);
                    $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else { // The server returned data, but there was an error on the server side.
                    $(".contact").append("<img src='BAD.jpg'>");
                }
            } else { // The server had a problem and didn't return any data.
                $(".contact").append("<img src='BAD.jpg'>");
            }
        }
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // There was an error in the AJAX call.
            $(".contact").append("<img src='BAD.jpg'>");
        },
    }
});

    return false; 
});
```

Also, you're using the `data` parameter wrong. Ignore the data section of the above example and use this as your data:

```
data: {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone
}
```

This looks strange to people who don't understand JavaScript objects. Let me know if you would like me to explain why we define the variables with the same names, e.g.: `name: name`.

Comment: Oh, this is also interesting!  I'll give this a try!

Comment: This can be simplified (and outdented) quite a bit by starting the success handler off like this: `if (!result || !result.success) { /* (output 'bad' image here) */; return; }`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have both `result.success` and `.append(result)`. This solution needs a server-side change to return JSON, and you'd want to have a `result.message` property for the text message.

Comment: That's a good way to do it too, Jan. Thanks!

nnnnnn: I simply copied their code and added their request. I didn't modify what they had posted, simply added to it.